# Can not install Apache2::Const module

Tags: perl, apache, module, failed-installation, mod-perl2

I have installed Apache 2.2.25 with mod_perl 2.0.7 running on Debian 7.1.0. During its installation mod_perl had to install module named **Apache2::Const**, but it didn't. mod_perl have installed modules from the same group, e.g. Apache2::Access, Apache2::Connection, Apache2::RequestUtil.

So when I use this command (i /Apache2::Const/) in cpan shell it outputs following:

```
cpan[3]> i /Apache2::Const/
Module id = Apache2::ConstantsTable
    CPAN_USERID  PHRED (Fred Moyer <fred@redhotpenguin.com>)
    CPAN_VERSION undef
    CPAN_FILE    P/PH/PHRED/mod_perl-2.0.8.tar.gz
    UPLOAD_DATE  2013-04-18
    INST_FILE    (not installed)
```

And when I use this command (install Apache2::Const):

```
cpan[4]> install Apache2::Const
Warning: Cannot install Apache2::Const, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /Apache2::Const/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

I've tried to run:

```
install Apache2::ConstantsTable
```

But it didn't help.

Also, when I run following script:

```
perl -e "use v5.14.2; use Apache2::Const"
```

it outputs:

```
Not a CODE reference at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/DynaLoader.pm line 207.
END failed--call queue aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/ModPerl/Const.pm line 207.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Apache2/Const.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Apache2/Const.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

I tried to install this module manually (via Makefile.PL) from mod_perl package. I also tried to reinstall mod_perl. Nothing helped.

All the other Apache2::* modules works correctly.

I really need to install **Apache2::Const** module. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I take it you aren't using the debian package? Why not?

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=636651

Comment: Richard Huxton, what do you mean? What debian package?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved long time ago by installing all this stuff from debian package. I was hard noob in linux when I posted the question.